# Igraph eigenvector centrality Run-Time error c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, igraph

I'm writing program on c++ that needs to generate graphs and calculate some measures.I'm working with Visual Studio 2013 and Igraph C library. At this point I can create graphs from custom info and calculate some metrics like betweennes and closeness centrality, but when i try to calculate eigenvector centrality, the program crash and show me this message:

> "Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'tgetv0' is being used without being initialized."

The tgetv0 variable is used inside of dgetv.c from Igraph source.
Here is my code:

```
void GraphObject::calcEigen()
{
igraph_arpack_options_t options;
igraph_real_t value;
igraph_vector_t weights;
igraph_vector_init(&weights, igraph_ecount(&cGraph));  //cGraph is already created.
igraph_vector_init(&eigenRes, igraph_vcount(&cGraph));  //All ..Res igraph_vector_t are declarated in header
igraph_vector_init(&betweennesRes, 0);
igraph_vector_init(&closenessRes, 0);
igraph_arpack_options_init(&options);

igraph_betweenness(&cGraph, &betweennesRes, igraph_vss_all(), 0, 0, 1);
igraph_closeness(&cGraph, &closenessRes, igraph_vss_all(), IGRAPH_ALL, 0, 1);
igraph_eigenvector_centrality(&cGraph, &eigenRes, &value, 0, 1, &weights, &options);
}
```

The closeness and betwenness are correctly calculated an "couted" but crash on eigenvector function.

After lot of research on documentation, internet and the debugger i cant't figure which is the problem, especially when I tryed the example code in the documentation http://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Structural.html#igraph_eigenvector_centrality (copy/paste) and makes the same. Is this a library or example issue, I a'm missing something?

When I init the weights vector and then I call igraph_null(&weights), it works but the result of all eigenvalues is 1, and this is incorrect result. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has to do something with the initialization of the `weights` variable. Does your graph have weights? If not, don't use the `weights` argument for the `igraph_eigenvector_centrality` call, just pass a null pointer there. If your graph does have weights, fill the `weights` vector first - right now it contains uninitialized values only.

Comment: Thank for reply Tamas. I thought that was the problem, but I tryed to pass a null pointer and still do the same. The graphs don't have weights, I tryed to fill weights vector with igraph_vector_fill(&weights, 10) and nothing... Stepbacking on my research I remember that the Msvc build have a bug with the IGRAPH_SUPPORT definition (solved by adding /DPRPACK_IGRAPH_SUPPORT=1 on command line). May this bug be the cause of the problem?

Comment: No, PRPACK has nothing to do with eigenvector centrality. I'm adding a possible answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that Visual Studio is right and we indeed have a variable named `tgetv0` that is being used uninitialized. I scanned igraph's source code and it looks like there are two places where it could indeed be the case. One of them is in `src/lapack/dnaupd.c`, the other one is in `src/lapack/dsaupd.c`. Both of these files were converted from Fortran using `f2c` so it is hard to tell whether the issue was present in the original Fortran code or whether this was introduced during the conversion. Either way, you can probably fix this easily by looking up the lines where `tgetv0` is declared in `src/lapack/dnaupd.c` and `src/lapack/dsaupd.c` and initializing it to a value of 0. In my version, the lines to change are line 486 in `src/lapack/dnaupd.c` and line 482 in `src/lapack/dsaupd.c`.

Please add a comment to confirm whether the solution works for you or not - if it works, I'll commit a patch to the igraph source tree.

Comment: It doesn't works, the same error pop up... I'll keep investigating. Thanks

Comment: The igraph_pagerank() function only works on IGRAPH_PAGERANK_ALGO_PRPACK mode, with the ARPACK mode the runtime error again, the IGRAPH_PAGERANK_ALGO_POWER is deprecated. Other thing tha i can see is that the igraph_sparsemat_init() function generates a unsolved external, even if in de igraph-0.7.1-msvc/debug path contains sparsemat.obj.